# converting the Picklist to Read only field in Visual Force

Tags: visualforce, attribute

Hi I have a Field on VF

```
    <apex:inputfield value="{!opObj.Product_Family__c}" required="false"  rendered="{!!isEdit}" onkeypress="return handlerKeyPress(event);"/>
 <apex:outputfield value="{!opObj.Product_Family__c}"   rendered="{!isEdit}"/>
```

changed it to

```
<apex:outputlabel value="{!opObj.Product_Family__c}" onmousemove="return handlerKeyPress(event);"  />
```

but the field value is not being displayed.
also using this field value i am having another lookup field to pull related records. that is also not working. earlier it used to work fine.
What went wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why are you changing a inputField (outputField if isEdit) into a outputLabel? What are you expecting? This is definitely not going to work.

Comment: It was a picklist on Opportunity.
I am bringing it on to VF as Picklist initially.
No i want it as Readonly field.

Comment: Then you should be using outputfield instead of outputlabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you have described in your comment. I believe you simply need to change the rendering logic in your original code:

```
 <apex:inputfield value="{!opObj.Product_Family__c}" required="false"  rendered="{!isEdit}" onkeypress="return handlerKeyPress(event);"/>
 <apex:outputfield value="{!opObj.Product_Family__c}"   rendered="{!!isEdit}"/>
```

This will work as a readonly field when it is not edit mode and an input field when it is.

Comment: Hi lance Shi,

It worked Half way according to requirement.
The Next Lookup field is not able to pull related records.
Without the change in code it is working fine.

Comment: @SamuelJackson Is the next lookup field another tag in your Visualforce page? Can you post the whole code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Atrribute `html-disabled="true"` solved the issue.